# Why is my lan connection stronger on my Laptop than other electronics?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, lan

On my laptop when I connect to wifi I get an average of 20-30mbps of download and 10-15mbps of upload with usually around 17 ping, but when connected to lan (ethernet cord) I tend to get about 69-84mbs of download, 10-15mbs of upload, as well as 12-ish ping. But the problem isn't with my PC, it's with my Nintendo switch, when I'm connected to wifi with my Switch I get around 15-35mbps of download (usually depending on how many people are in my house connected to it) and 7mbps of upload. When I plug my ethernet cord to the switch I still get the same results as if I wasn't using lan at all. Why is my lan stronger on my PC than my switch? Or is this normal?

edit: yes you're right saying faster would be better than stronger, my bad. Also yes I am connected to lan, it shows it on the switch home menu, as well as when im doing the connection test itself.

edit 2: yes I verified its connected to ethernet

Comment: It might be better to say "faster" than stronger. As for your issue, are you certain the switch isn't still using the wireless connection when you're testing?

Comment: Try temporarily disabling WiFi on the Switch by enabling Airplane Mode, then run another speed test and see what upload and download speeds you get when you're 100% sure it isn't defaulting to WiFi despite being connected via Ethernet. Airplane Mode only disables the three wireless radios: WiFi, Bluetooth and NFC, Ethernet will be unaffected.

Comment: Did you verify your Switch is actually using the Ethernet connection?

Answer (score 1):

As you know, in most and usual cases, Ethernet/wired connection is faster than WiFi/wireless. And network speed depends on CPU power, regardless wired or wireless. The more power a device has, the higher speed it can get.

Even if Nintendo Switch is only a device that use network, its network performance is limited by its power, especially CPU power and NIC(Network Interface Card) power.

Regards,